# OnTriggerEnter2D() triggers TakeDamage() several times

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I'm trying to create multiplayer game with Network For Gameobjects
On the host I only deal damage once while on the client I deal damage about 3-5 times per hit.
Here is my enemyStats script:

```
public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        base.OnNetworkSpawn();
        singleton = this;
        health.Value = enemyData.HP;
        damage.Value = enemyData.Damage;

        // event
        MeleeCollision.onDamaged += TakeDamageServerRpc;

        health.OnValueChanged += (int previousHealth, int newHealth) =>
        {
            health.Value = newHealth;
        };
    }

    public override void OnNetworkDespawn()
    {
        base.OnNetworkDespawn();

        // event
        MeleeCollision.onDamaged -= TakeDamageServerRpc;
    }

    private void TakeDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
        health.Value -= damageAmount;
        Debug.Log("enemystats message: hit");
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    private void TakeDamageServerRpc(int damageAmount)
    {
        TakeDamage(damageAmount);
    }
```

and meleeCillision script:

```
public static Action<int> onDamaged;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            onDamaged?.Invoke(PlayerStats.singleton.damage.Value);
            Debug.Log("MeleeCollision message: hit");
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

I was trying to add bool state in onTrigger fuction but this didn't work

P.S. I found that the problem is that the client instantiates about 5 slash prefabs per click. here is the code which is responsible for this:

```
[Header("Attack")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject slashPrefab;
    [SerializeField] private Transform spawnPoint;
    [SerializeField] private float attackDelay = 0.5f;
    private NetworkVariable<bool> isAttacked = new NetworkVariable<bool>(false);
    private Quaternion fixRotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);


    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        base.OnNetworkSpawn();
        isAttacked.OnValueChanged += (bool previousValue, bool newValue) =>
        {
            isAttacked.Value = newValue;
            Debug.Log(isAttacked.Value);
        };
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !isAttacked.Value) AttackServerRpc(spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation, attackDelay);
    }

    private IEnumerator Attack(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, float delay)
    {
        isAttacked.Value = true;
        var prefab = Instantiate(slashPrefab, position, rotation * fixRotation);
        prefab.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        isAttacked.Value = false;
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    private void AttackServerRpc(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, float delay)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Attack(position, rotation, delay));
    }
```

Comment: in general networked physics is a lot of fun ;) is it maybe possible that the same collision is handled multiple times by different clients and the host?

Answer (score 0):

@derHugo in his comment is right. I think the same collision is handled multiple times. I added float damageCooldown to store the cooldown time and a dictionary to store the time of the last collision for each enemy.

Try it and see if it fixes your issue

```
public class MeleeCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Action<int> onDamaged;

    
    public float damageCooldown = 0.5f;
    private Dictionary<GameObject, float> lastHitTime;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lastHitTime = new Dictionary<GameObject, float>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            if (!lastHitTime.ContainsKey(other.gameObject) || Time.time - lastHitTime[other.gameObject] > damageCooldown)
            {
                onDamaged?.Invoke(PlayerStats.singleton.damage.Value);
                lastHitTime[other.gameObject] = Time.time;
                Debug.Log("MeleeCollision message: hit");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an addendum to the question above. the problem turned out to be in the script that instantiates the attack